# Content-Projection: Passing data into a projected Component

Tags: validation, angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to create a generic ReactiveForms-Frameworks, which handles the creation of an Reactive-Form as well as the validation. I created a repo here https://github.com/DrMueller/Ng-ReactiveValidation to tinker around with this idea.
I have an Interface called IFormWithValidation, which holds the FormGroup as well as the logical Controls, which can get validated. I also have a Form-Control Component, which receives such a logical Control as Input. 
This FormControl-Component is looking like this:

```
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div [class.has-error]="validatedControl.hasErrors">
      <div class="row">
        <ng-content select=".form__contentselector--body">
        </ng-content>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <app-form-validation-error-display [errorContainer]="validatedControl.errorContainer"></app-form-validation-error-display>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The ValidatedControl-Object like this:

```
export class ValidatedControl {
  private _errorContainer = ControlValidationErrorContainer.nullObject;

  public get errorContainer(): ControlValidationErrorContainer {
    return this._errorContainer;
  }

  public static create(controlName: string) {
    return new ValidatedControl(controlName);
  }

  constructor(public controlName: string) {
  }

  public get hasErrors(): boolean {
    return this.errorContainer.validationErrors.length > 0;
  }

  public setValidationErrors(validationErrors: ValidationError[]) {
    this._errorContainer.setValidationErrors(validationErrors);
  }
}
```

As you can see in the HTML, i also have a SubComponent, which is responsible to show the validation-errors, if there are some. This Component is quite trivial, receiving an Array of errors and showing them:

```
    <div class="help-block">
      <ul class="app__ul--errors">
        <li *ngFor="let validationError of errorContainer.validationErrors">
          {{ validationError.errorMessage }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Tied everything together, I then can define a Form with content-projection and just pass the ValidatedControl instance:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    Hello POC
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="form.formGroup" novalidate>
      <fieldset>
        <app-form-control [formGroup]="form.formGroup" [validatedControl]="form.getValidatedControl('nameIdentifierControl')">
          <div class="form__contentselector--body">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <input class="form-control" id="nameIdentifierId" type="text" placeholder="User-Login (required)" formControlName="nameIdentifierControl"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </app-form-control>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem: The FormControl-Component sets and fills the error-display one, but that's problematic: The Client can't decide where to put it. In this example, the result is quite ugly, since the Label and Control are defined by the Client-Projection, but the errors not:

[image: Ugly validation]

So, I'd kindahow would like to let the Client decide, where to place the validation, but I'd not want to pass ValidatedControl-Instance twice. Is content-projection even the correct proceeding?